# Ошибка при заполнении массива строками C++

Tags: c++, qt

При увеличении переменной j выскакивает исключение ошибки чтения по адресу.

```
QString* Plugin::getPluginList()
{
    int j = NULL;

    int i = NULL;

    QString* pluginArray = new QString[Plugin::getNumberOfPlugins()]; // массив размеров кол-ва строк в файле

    QFile file(Plugin::getPathToPluginListSkyrimSe() + Plugin::getPluginListFileName()); //путь до файла, он корректный

    if ((file.exists()) && (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))) {

        QString pluginName = "";

        while (!file.atEnd()) {

            if (i >= 2) {

                pluginName = file.readLine();

                pluginArray[j] = pluginName;
            }

            i++;
            j++; // вот здесь выбрасывает исключение, когда я увеличиваю переменную j 
        }

        file.close();
    }

    return pluginArray;
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас переменным `int` задаются значения `NULL`? Это, конечно, должен быть дефайн на 0, но выглядит неинтуитивно

Comment: @artaxerx, дело вкуса

Comment: сделайте вы `QVector<QString> pluginArray`. У вас явно выход за пределы. Также неплохо было бы увидеть что за исключение выбрасывается.

Comment: @goldstar_labs "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFC7326771E (Qt5Cored.dll) в EternalModManager.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF."

Comment: проверьте в дебаге в момент исключения, чему равно j, больше чем Plugin::getNumberOfPlugins() ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, при входе в цикл j = 0, длинна массива = 3, дело не в массиве я думаю, вообще раньше у меня эта конструкция работала прекрасно.

Comment: Наверняка _  раньше строки в файле были меньше, чем Plugin::getNumberOfPlugins(), а теперь  это условие не выполняется....